# Why is my OLE data source data not querying consistently?

Tags: c#, excel, date, oledb

I have a Microsoft Excel 2003 file that I am querying from C# 2.0 using an OleDbConnection.

One of the cells in the Excel file is formated as a short date and displays in Excel as "1/1/2009".  If I change the format to General the text displayed in that cell changes to "39814".

If I query the Excel file while the **file is open**, I receive **"39814"** in the result set.

If I query the Excel file while the **file is closed**, I receive **"1/1/2009"** in the result set.

Why the inconsistency with importing data from this Ole Data Source?

Thank you,
Keith

Comment: Interesting, I may try to duplicate this if I have time this morning.